# Picking image programmatically from gallery

Tags: android, bitmap, cursor

I tried the below code to get the image from sdcard programmatically. But I am getting "outofmemoryerror". Please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView image;
    public static final String uri = "content://media/external/images/media";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Uri path = Uri.parse(uri);
        String[] filepath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(path, filepath, null, null,
                null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String imagepath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filepath[0]));
        Log.i("siva", "siva" + imagepath);
        image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath));

    }

}
```

logcat :

```
02-26 18:35:18.069: D/dalvikvm(25010): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 52K, 9% free 9508K/10371K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
02-26 18:35:18.159: I/dalvikvm-heap(25010): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.244MB for 20155408-byte allocation
02-26 18:35:18.629: D/dalvikvm(25010): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 29190K/30087K, paused 3ms+37ms, total 468ms
02-26 18:35:18.629: D/dalvikvm(25010): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
02-26 18:35:19.060: D/libEGL(25010): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_hawaii.so
02-26 18:35:19.070: D/(25010): mem_init ++
02-26 18:35:19.070: D/(25010): gHwMemAllocator client 3
02-26 18:35:19.070: D/(25010): **** Using ION allocator ****
02-26 18:35:19.070: D/(25010): registered SIGUSR1[10] for pid[25010]
02-26 18:35:19.070: D/(25010): HwMemAllocatorImpl Static Counters 0 0
02-26 18:35:19.070: D/(25010): HwMemAllocatorImpl[4adcad5c] totalDeviceAllocSize[0] totalFree[0] maxFree[0] in numSlabs[0]
02-26 18:35:19.080: D/(25010): mem_init 4adcad5c--
02-26 18:35:19.080: D/ION(25010): config: version(0x10000) secure(0xf000) 256M(0x22d) fast(0x608) hwwr(0x608)
02-26 18:35:19.080: D/(25010): Waiting for mm thread to come up
02-26 18:35:19.080: D/(25010): Waiting for mm thread to come up
02-26 18:35:19.080: D/(25010): mm_device_thread starting
02-26 18:35:19.080: D/HAWAII_EGL(25010): eglCreateContext() config: 35 context: 0x4c92a450, VC context 1, Thread 25010
02-26 18:35:19.090: D/HAWAII_EGL(25010): Set SWAP INTERVAL 0
02-26 18:35:19.090: D/HAWAII_EGL(25010): eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4d0618a0, VC surface: 1, Thread: 25010
02-26 18:35:19.090: D/HAWAII_EGL(25010): eglMakeCurrent(0x4c92a450, 0x4d0618a0, 0x4d0618a0) Thread: 25010
02-26 18:35:19.100: D/OpenGLRenderer(25010): Enabling debug mode 0
02-26 18:35:19.720: W/OpenGLRenderer(25010): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2592x1944, max=2048x2048)
02-26 18:35:19.760: D/HAWAII_EGL(25010): eglMakeCurrent(0x4c92a450, 0x4d286310, 0x4d286310) Thread: 25010
02-26 18:35:19.760: D/HAWAII_EGL(25010): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 25010
02-26 18:35:22.613: D/HAWAII_EGL(25010): eglMakeCurrent(0x4c92a450, 0x4d286310, 0x4d286310) Thread: 25010
02-26 18:35:22.613: D/HAWAII_EGL(25010): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 25010
02-26 18:35:23.214: D/HAWAII_EGL(25010): eglMakeCurrent(0x4c92a450, 0x4d0618a0, 0x4d0618a0) Thread: 25010
02-26 18:35:23.704: D/HAWAII_EGL(25010): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 25010
02-26 18:35:23.704: D/HAWAII_EGL(25010): eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4d0618a0, android window 0x4c925438, Thread: 25010
02-26 18:35:24.104: D/dalvikvm(25010): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 48K, 3% free 29259K/30087K, paused 19ms, total 22ms
02-26 18:35:24.104: I/dalvikvm-heap(25010): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 20155408-byte allocation
02-26 18:35:24.125: D/dalvikvm(25010): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 11K, 3% free 29247K/30087K, paused 22ms, total 23ms
02-26 18:35:24.125: E/dalvikvm-heap(25010): Out of memory on a 20155408-byte allocation.
-2602 18:35:24.135: I/dalvikvm(25010): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
02-26 18:35:24.135: I/dalvikvm(25010):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40dbe508 self=0x40dae228
02-26 18:35:24.135: I/dalvikvm(25010):   | sysTid=25010 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074786096
02-26 18:35:24.135: I/dalvikvm(25010):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=56 stm=18 core=0
02-26 18:35:24.135: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
02-26 18:35:24.165: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:663)
02-26 18:35:24.165: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:392)
02-26 18:35:24.165: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:457)
02-26 18:35:24.165: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at com.example.sivareddy1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
02-26 18:35:24.165: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
02-26 18:35:24.185: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-26 18:35:24.195: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
02-26 18:35:24.195: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
02-26 18:35:24.195: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3590)
02-26 18:35:24.195: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-26 18:35:24.195: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
02-26 18:35:24.195: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 18:35:24.205: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
02-26 18:35:24.205: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
02-26 18:35:24.205: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 18:35:24.215: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 18:35:24.225: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-26 18:35:24.225: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-26 18:35:24.225: I/dalvikvm(25010):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 18:35:24.225: W/CursorWrapperInner(25010): Cursor finalized without prior close()
02-26 18:35:24.225: D/skia(25010): --- decoder->decode returned false
02-26 18:35:24.265: D/AndroidRuntime(25010): Shutting down VM
02-26 18:35:24.265: W/dalvikvm(25010): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dbd2a0)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:663)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:392)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:457)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at com.example.sivareddy1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3590)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-26 18:35:24.275: E/AndroidRuntime(25010):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 18:35:24.385: W/CursorWrapperInner(25010): Binder has been finalized, ise=java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
```

Comment: possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

On Android, loading a bitmap in memory is something really sensitive. You have to care about the picture size. The memory allocation do not depends on the actual file weight but more of the size of the picture itself.

Here is a good lecture you should consider reading about Android, Pictures loading and memory efficiency:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html